# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS when they are CDN

Tags: javascript, css

I'm getting the infamous **Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content** on google's PageSpeed. The thing is that all my .js and .css resources are CDN and all of them are minified.

I was able to get rid of the .js warning by adding the `async` attribute to the `<script>` as suggested by google but I haven't found a workaround yet for the .css warnings which are `foundation.min.css`, `font-awesome.min.css` and `fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,900,100`. Any suggestions? Thanks.